# Integrating twitter with android

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I am integrating twitter in my android application , so that I am able to tweet a piece of information to my tweet list .

I am following this article .

```
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_twitter_integration.htm
```

Firstly , like other platforms (example FB ) , I had to create an application at apps.twitter.
I did the above.

Secondly I had to change the permissions on the application to Read , write and access direct messages. When I tried doing so , it said I need to register my cellphone with twitter.

Off I went to my profile settings `https://twitter.com/settings/devices` 
and attempted to add my cellphone number in there. It told me to text GO on 8080.

This is where my road ends. No matter how many times I've tried , I never get an acknowledgment from 8080.

Is there any alternate way to integrate twitter with android ? . Can you please suggest anything at all ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow [this](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/AndroidTwitter) for integrating twitter.

You just need to pass twitter_consumer_key and twitter_secret_key.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Please try my library: https://github.com/antonkrasov/AndroidSocialNetworks

With help of it you will have an ability to post tweets easily:

```
mSocialNetworkManager.getTwitterSocialNetwork().requestPostMessage(message,
            new DemoOnPostingCompleteListener(message)
    );

private class DemoOnPostingCompleteListener implements OnPostingCompleteListener {
    private String mmMessage;

    private DemoOnPostingCompleteListener(String message) {
        mmMessage = message;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostSuccessfully(int socialNetworkID) {
        hideProgress();

        handleSuccess("Success", "Message: '" + mmMessage + "' successfully posted.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int socialNetworkID, String requestID, String errorMessage, Object data) {
        hideProgress();
        handleError(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

Please ask, if you have other questions :)

Comment: Anton this looks promising , let me give this a try and get back to you